# How to manage dependent dropdown list in php when create and update method is managed in same page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, html-select

I have written the code to display the dependent dropdown list in php, when I create the record it is working. What changes I need to do while updating the record as I want the create and update method in same page.
Here's the code for reference,

```html
<div class="form-group row m-b-15">
    <label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-form-label" for="fin_is_fin_req">
        Is Finance Required? * :
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <select name="fin_is_fin_req" id="is_finance" class="form-control" autofocus>
            <option value="">-Select Finance-</option>
            <?php
                $fin_req=array('Yes','No');
                foreach ($fin_req as $list) {
                    if ($allotment->fin_is_fin_req==$list):?>
            <option selected value="<?=$list?>">
                <?php else:?>
            </option>
            <option value="<?=$list?>">
                <?php endif;?>
                <?=$list?></option>
            <?php } ?
            </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row m-b-15 ">
    <label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-form-label" for="fin_stage">
        Finance Stage * :
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <select name="fin_stage" id="stages" class="form-control">

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#is_finance').on('change', function () {
        var finance_value = $("#is_finance").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/loadstages.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: 'finance_value=' + finance_value
        }).done(function (stages) {
            stages = JSON.parse(stages);
            stages.forEach(function (stage) {
                $('#stages').append('<option value=' + stage.id + '>' + stage.stage_name + '</option>')
            })
        })

    });
});
```

loadstages.php

```php
if (isset($_POST['finance_value'])) {
    if ($_POST['finance_value'] == "Yes") {
        $stages = FinStage::select('*', 'state=1');
        //select(rows,where)
    } else {
        $stages = FinStage::select('*', 'state=0');
    }
}
echo
json_encode($stages);
```

//screenshot during insert

[image: screenshot during insert]

//screenshot during update

[image: screenshot during update]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you are saying that when you open the page, you want that page to show that second select, if the first dropdown has a value saved to it already? If that is the case, you can load it initially with PHP initially or you can adjust your JS to load the first dropdown at page ready:

```
<script>
// I might consider making this an object for reuse
class FormController
{
    fetch(data, page, success)
    {
        $.ajax({
            // Presumably all your ajax files are in this directory
            url: `ajax/${page}.php`,
            method: 'post',
            data: data
        }).done(r => {
            // If your ajax pages send headers for Content-Type: application/json,
            // you can skip the JSON parse if you want to
            success(JSON.parse(r));
        });
    }
}
// If you extend the main form, you can use the ajax
class Finance extends FormController
{
    getStages()
    {
        // Fetch the value from dropdown
        const finance_value = $("#is_finance").val();
        // Fetch the value of the first dropdown
        super.fetch({ finance_value }, 'loadstages', r => {
            // Do your append loop from the return
            r.forEach(stage => {
                $('#stages').append(`<option value=${stage.id}>${stage.stage_name}</option>`);
            });
        });
    }
}
// Document ready
$(() => {
    // Create the financial form
    var FinForm = new Finance();
    // Fetch the select value on page load
    FinForm.getStates();
    // On change, fetch the value again
    $('#is_finance').on('change', () => {
        FinForm.getStates();
    });
});

</script>
```

Your PHP probably should be more like:

```
<?php
# Consider using this header
// header('Content-Type: application/json');
# Set a default, makes sure the json doesn't throw a warning if the condition
# is not set for whatever reason
$stage = [];
if (isset($_POST['finance_value'])) {
    $finAffirm = ($_POST['finance_value'] == "Yes");
    # You can just do this in one line so there is no duplication
    $stages = FinStage::select('*', 'state='.(($finAffirm)? '1' : '0'));
    # Fetch only on the affirmative
    if ($finAffirm) {
        //select(rows,where)
    }
}
# It's safer just to exit here
die(json_encode($stages));
```